# What is the WordPress style / best-practice of CSS formatting called?

Tags: css, wordpress

What's the name for the [CSS style / best-practice that WordPress uses](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/css/)?

I ask because, with PHP, we have `Pear style`, `GNU style`, `K&R`, etc... Is there any keyword or name for the css style used by WP?

Is there a nomenclature for css formatting conventions at all?

**ie:**

```
.this,
.and-this {
  display: none;
}
```

rather than:

```
.this,.and-this{display: none;}
```

[Drupal has CSS formatting guidelines](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/css/css-formatting-guidelines) as well. But, I'm unable to find any resource [except maybe this one](https://css-tricks.com/different-ways-to-format-css/) which gives titles to different css formatting conventions in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special CSS that WordPress uses: it just employs regular old CSS like any other site. That page you linked to is showing *preferred* syntax conventions. I just skimmed through the page and the examples of CSS syntax that they don't like were marked **incorrect** ... even though most would actually function just fine from what I can tell. A little misleading.

Regarding your two snippets above: those will have the same results (though in the second one you need a space after the comma: `.this, .and-this{display: none;}`). The first snippet referred to as human-friendly or human-readable, with extra whitespace and line breaks to make it easier for people to read and write. The second is simply minified for faster processing by computers, which removes whitespacing and line breaks.

It should be noted that this principle of minification from your example really only applies when scaled up to hundreds/thousands of lines of code and doesn't make much of a difference with less than that.

Comment: I'm asking specifically regarding the [WordPress.org best practices](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/css/). I'll rewrite the question to clarify. Great answer none the less, thank you